# Slick Plain Sql Generic Return Type

Tags: sql, scala, generics, slick

I am trying to write a configurable sql query executor using Slick. User provides a prepared statement with ? and at run time the exact query is formed by replacing ? with values.

Generally this is how one would run a plain sql query using slick.

```
val query = sql"#$queryString".as[(String,Int)]
```

In my case i would not know the result type so i want to get back a generic result type. Maybe a List of Tuples with each tuple representing a row of result SET.

Any ideas on how this would be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution from one of the scala git issues. Here it is

```
ResultMap extends GetResult[Map[String, Any]] {
  def apply(pr: PositionedResult) = {
    val resultSet = pr.rs
    val metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
    (1 to pr.numColumns).map { i =>
      metaData.getColumnName(i) -> resultSet.getObject(i)
    }.toMap
  }
```

and then we can simply do `val query = sql"#$queryString".as(ResultMap)`

Hope it helps!!